# Session Variable Member?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I'm using a compiled .dll provided by someone else -- I know little about it, other than it has a session variable that I must access in a way that is strange to me.  Not sure what to call it -- have googled for words that I thought might be right, but so far no success.  Here is what it looks like:

Session("receipt").username

It's the .username part that I don't understand.  What is it?  How is it created?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried opening it in reflector to have a look how it is used? (Assuming it is a .net assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is probably a global object which has a default property which returns a SessionItem object. The SessionItem object is loaded from the browser-session (probably) by the Session object. The SessionItem object has a property username, which is a value stored somewhere in the browser-session.

Some code to clear things up:

```
Public Class Session
    Private Items As SessionItemCollection

    Default Public ReadOnly Property SessionItem(ByVal id As String) As Object
        Get
            Return Me.Items.Find(id)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And you calling the code (Which searches for the "receipt" item in the SessionItemCollection Items from Session):

```
Session("receipt")
```

Comment: Thank you -- that had been driving me crazy.  "Session Item Object"  After you named it, I was able to google it, and found a great explanation on codeproject for how to use it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/SessionDiagram.aspx?display=Print.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and you are allowed to mark my answer as your answer if you like hehe

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (since there isn't much other code to go off of) is that the object being stored in the session variable and accessed via `Session("receipt")` is of a class that contains a property or member called `username` which you are accessing in that fashion.

The basic idea is that `Session("receipt")` will pull back whatever this object is (for the sake of instruction we will say it is a receipt object) and the `.username` is referencing the username property of that receipt object.